# How do I evaluate the performance of my image-to-image regression model?

Tags: regression, neural-networks, image-processing

I have created a neural network that performs image-to-image regression from grayscale images to distance maps of the input images. The ground truth images are created by creating the distance map of the binary segmentation mask of the image but the target output is just the distance map with the same size as the input image. The purpose of generating the distance map is to use them for segmentation.

Is there a generally accepted way of evaluating the performance of image-to-image regression models? Is the MSE or similar metrics generally used for this type of task?